# Create an object that contains property names of another object

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a TS validated utility that iterates over the first level properties of the object and returns a new one with its property name.

JS-wise it's quite straightforward, but I would appreciate a bit if you can help me a bit define a correct type structure. I've created a [TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgBAKgngDgpgZzCYAoALrOYDyAjAKzgGN0B1AS3QAsBldAJwoDsBzJAXjAG9Ux%20wAbRYATOAA8AXGASMWrALrTZTNqgC%20qDFjABJZujgMAZgENicAEokK8AMIB7ALYwHzOAc48%20AlsYcMTqboFG7SeA4OADZwpsw%20-PIMcCIUHugI4ZExcQlgTnA0DiJZ0bHxmtrwegZGZhbWxLZwji5u6QgA0nBQXrwCYH4BQSFhMnJqA0kpaZ7KE6x5BUUl46qLlaBgADIOrBTEyGjGAK7MpKHMYMTJwXD4RKTdvQA8EACMADSQAEwAfGAABQOQgkdDSD4ASghP28A2IblkYAA1j1MrhQaRKDR6Os%20pUBg8wQA6VG9YGY9CQ4n%20BgAUXM1EBgJgDAc8AYmAAcqYCpCwBwAf0BgIyQhBKz2UZuby4AoBWBJRyZQU8upIVoBsl0CcGFcxWBTEgID8NFpUAjmEjkk17M5XO45jVDCZzFYbHa2o6MgrhYlmLSRpdpGYogg4J88tNUh1pIwThGloVqMU4wwE2bUBJXJzroj0GAbc1Wg6Os8vDdYoYiU80S99C76u7bS17e1PN8G3U3Y1i23vV00X9AUXPaXPBqLYiysSonsRx7W16y2jiUNAsFLpCgA) with the code example

P.S: Feel free to drop any suggestion on type refactor if you know a better way :-)

Comment: Why do you want to create an object that maps each key to itself? If you just want a list of keys, you could just have an array of keys, which `Object.keys()` can make for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is absolutely possible and simple with a mapped type:

```
type PropMap<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: K;
};
```

And then we change the definition of the function to return this:

```
function createObjectKeys<T> (object: T): PropMap<T> {
```

Unfortunately a cast is required here:

```
    return keys as PropMap<T>;
```

But if you try it in the playground below you'll see that it produces the correct types:

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgBAKgngDgpgZzCYAoALrOYDyAjAKzgGN0B1AS3QAsBldAJwoDsBzJAXjAG9Ux+wAbRYATOAA8AXGASMWrALrTZTNqgC+qDFjABJZujgMAZgENicAEokK8AMIB7ALYwHzOAc48+AlsYcMTqboFG7SeA4OADZwpsw+-PIMcCIUHugI4ZExcQlgTnA0DiJZ0bHxmtrwYAAKDA4wALKmMAA8EAB8YFy8AkIA0mAsYADWcFAOxpBKYP0A3BoLqKBgADIOrBTEyGjGAK7MpKHMYMTJwXD4RKT94wjtXQAUDoQk6NIQAJTSdQ3NbZ1vH1iG5ZKM7tIrm9KDR6Kp2N0eJU+lDSAA6MZQBDPV6kT5o-wMACi5moj0eMHq8AYmAAcqYCp9ul1en0BJiEIJKQ0jHSGXAFIjudS+QU8upPlo+sl0HsGCcOWBTEhfk0Wg8NFpUCDmGDksRbHBHC43OlMnoDEYzBZrAb7M5XO5PIjWYlmISgiEwmAzFEEHAADR5JIpNKeaSMPaBvIFIolMCRuCa1ASVw006g9BgfWG42Os23LGIs6xQyo9CF7E5+0mp0ZSXa0FlNFRDaPatGh2mzyVtF+AKe46fIA)

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need to create any type helper for this, your object itself holds sufficient info to make the code snippet work

```
/* Types */
type ObjectWithStrings = {
    [index: string]: string
}

type InterfaceRecipeComponents = {
    information: boolean
    ingredients: boolean
    method: boolean
}

/* Logic */
function createObjectKeys<T1, _R = { [k in keyof T1 ]: k }> (object: T1): _R {
    const keys: ObjectWithStrings  =  {}

    Object.keys(object).forEach((propertyName) => {
        keys[propertyName] = propertyName
    })

    return keys as unknown as  _R
}


const recipeComponents: InterfaceRecipeComponents = {
    information: false,
    ingredients: true,
    method: true
}

export const recipeComponentsKeys = createObjectKeys(recipeComponents)

console.log(recipeComponentsKeys.test)
```

[Code Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgBAKgngDgpgZzCYAoALrOYDyAjAKzgGN0B1AS3QAsBldAJwoDsBzJAXjAG9Ux%20wAbRYATOAA8AXGASMWrALrTZTNqgC%20qDFjABJZujgMAZgENicAEokK8AMIB7ALYwHzOAc48%20AlsYcMTqboFG7SeA4OADZwpsw%20-PIMcCIUHugI4ZExcQlgTnA0DiJZ0bHxmqigYAAyDqwUxMhoxgCuzKShzGDEycFw%20ESkANJwUAgAPBAAjAA0YAD6lmBc3EIA1mAsYOtjDsaQ02BKO2DqAHxgABQOhCTo0jMAlNJL3gI9brI7Y5m4d6RKDR6Kp2PwuDxKh9BvcAHS7cY3AHoJ6w-wMACi5moVyuMAYDngDEwADlTAUnitLrwPh8EQhBPjCUZSeS4AoVmAmUTWQU8uonloPsl0K0GN16WBTEh2utmA4AO7daX8JYaLSoYhfdBgZLEWxwRwuNzpP76QwmcxWGz2ZyudyeTk03zMdFBEJhMBmKIIOCzPJJFJpTzSRitP15ApFEpgMNwdWoCSuYmfZjfPUGo3202jcac3qxQwwka-K4Z23Gh0ZQWar5lWFReplm2Gu0mzy5hCwwyyQVAA)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, Bishwajit. With this approach, the unexisting properties of the returned object can be accessed without a typescript warning. Give it a try by accessing `recipeComponentsKeys.test` inside the console.log

Comment: @volna got it, I have edited my code block to handle that case as well.